# How can I make the UUIDField shorter in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, uuid

So for my webapp, I have this code for my Post model

```py
import uuid   
id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

So that's all fine and well, but I get this error when I go to create a Post object. But I get this error

`Python int too large to convert to SQLite INTEGER`

So I need to somehow shorten the length of it down to something like 12 so I don't get this error, but I haven't been able to find anything anywhere on how to do this in Django.

Here is the Post model (I left out all unrelated things)

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='posts',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(
        default='',
        editable=False,
        max_length=75,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

And here is my DetailView

```py
class PostListView(HitCountDetailView,SelectRelatedMixin,TagMixin,ListView):
    model = Post    
    count_hit = True
    template_name = 'mainapp/post_list.html'
    selected_related = ("user","group")
    paginate_by = 10
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    queryset = models.Post.objects.all()

    def get(self,request):
        posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-published_date')
        users = User.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id)
        count= User.objects.all().count()
        friend, created = Friend.objects.get_or_create(current_user=request.user)
        friends = friend.users.all()
        group = Group.objects.all()
        args = {
            'users':users, 'friends':friends, 'posts':posts, 'group':group,'count':count,
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-published_date')
```

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\interests-site-Ho6yLlHE\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\interests-site-Ho6yLlHE\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\interests-site-Ho6yLlHE\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\interests-site-Ho6yLlHE\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\interests-site-Ho6yLlHE\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\interests-site\interests\mainapp\views.py", line 255, in get
    return render(request, self.template_name, args)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\interests-site-Ho6yLlHE\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 36, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\interests-site-Ho6yLlHE\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\interests-site-Ho6yLlHE\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\interests-site-Ho6yLlHE\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\interests-site-Ho6yLlHE\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\interests-site-Ho6yLlHE\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\interests-site-Ho6yLlHE\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\interests-site-Ho6yLlHE\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\interests-site-Ho6yLlHE\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\interests-site-Ho6yLlHE\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\interests-site-Ho6yLlHE\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\interests-site-Ho6yLlHE\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\interests-site-Ho6yLlHE\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\interests-site-Ho6yLlHE\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\interests-site-Ho6yLlHE\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 209, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\interests-site-Ho6yLlHE\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\interests-site-Ho6yLlHE\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 188, in render
    return template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\interests-site-Ho6yLlHE\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 173, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\interests-site-Ho6yLlHE\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\interests-site-Ho6yLlHE\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\interests-site-Ho6yLlHE\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\interests-site-Ho6yLlHE\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 166, in render
    len_values = len(values)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\interests-site-Ho6yLlHE\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 256, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\interests-site-Ho6yLlHE\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1242, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\interests-site-Ho6yLlHE\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 55, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\interests-site-Ho6yLlHE\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1133, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\interests-site-Ho6yLlHE\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 103, in execute
    sql = self.db.ops.last_executed_query(self.cursor, sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\interests-site-Ho6yLlHE\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\operations.py", line 150, in last_executed_query
    params = self._quote_params_for_last_executed_query(params)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\interests-site-Ho6yLlHE\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\operations.py", line 139, in _quote_params_for_last_executed_query
    return cursor.execute(sql, params).fetchone()
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to SQLite INTEGER
[05/Jan/2020 01:42:45] "GET /mainapp/posts/ HTTP/1.1" 500 278808
```

Comment: Your syntax seems correct. Did you run make migrations & migrate?

Comment: Yep. Everything else in the project is working. And I just looked at the admin panel, and the posts are being saved. But I can't view or edit them because I get the error. I'm just a bit stumped on what to do

Comment: Please provide full code where your models are defined and code you use to view/edit. Can't help any more than what has been provided.

Comment: Added the related model and the Detail View. When I said I can't edit them, I meant on the admin page

Comment: It would be useful if you included the full traceback of your error as well.

Comment: Oops, I forgot that, added now

Comment: The traceback is incomplete.

Comment: Ok thanks for that, I have now added the full traceback

Comment: Your code works fine but error says that int too large to convert to SQLite INTEGER. It can not hold your input data because your data is to large. Sqlite integers are signed 64-bit values. It does not have any concept of an unsigned type.

Comment: Is there anyway to make the int smaller in Django?

Comment: Could you provide versions of sqlite and django please?

Comment: Django 2.2.8 and sqlite3.

Comment: You can increase that id = models.BigIntegerField(unique=True, primary_key=True). but test in another db if its works fine then try in your system.

Comment: After doing that, I am now getting this error `invalid literal for int() with base 10: '5a17c16b252942548f026f3fdcf4578a'`

Comment: Try deleting/renaming the database, re-initialising a new one with Django (+ running migrations). My suspicion is that the database has the `id` key set to an incorrect data type when the database was fist created.

Comment: I am now getting this error `NOT NULL constraint failed: mainapp_post.id`
And now the Post object isn't getting saved in the database art all.